# Difficulty to manipulate Borel Cantelli lemma

Tags: probability, logic

I am trying to solve the following exercise :

Let $X_1,X_2, ...$ be independent. Show that $sup X_n < \infty$ a.s. if and only if $\sum P(X_n > A) < \infty$ for some A.

I want to show the "only if" part by showing that

$\sum P(X_n > A) = \infty$ for all A $\Rightarrow P(sup X_n = \infty)>0$

It's possible that my logic is already wrong but for me the opposite of "$sup X_n < \infty$ a.s" is $P(sup X_n = \infty)>0$

My attempt until now : By using the Borel Cantelli lemma for independent events I obtain, for all A $P(X_n>A$ infinitely often$) = 1$. I can use A for all the integer : for all $m \in \mathbb{N}, \exists N_m$ s.t $P(N_m)=0$ and $\forall \omega \in \Omega - N_m,  X_n(\omega) > m$ infinitely often. I can rewrite this as $ \forall m \in \mathbb{N}, \exists N_m$ s.t $P(N_m)=0$ and $\forall \omega \in \Omega - N_m, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \exists N > n$ s.t $X_n(\omega)>m$

By using that the discrete union of negligible event is still negligible I obtain :
$\forall \omega \in \Omega - \cup_{m \in \mathbb{N}} N_m, \forall m, \forall n, \exists N>n$ s.t $X_n(\omega)>m$ i.e
$\forall \omega \in \Omega - \cup_{m \in \mathbb{N}} N_m, supX_n(\omega)=+\infty$ i.e
$P(supX_n=+\infty)=1$ which is **stronger that what I really want to show** so I was wondering if there is a mistake in my proof.

Comment: There is  nothing wrong at all in what you have done. Have you heard of the 0-1 law of Kolomogorov?  If $X_i$'s are independent then the event $\{\sup X_n =\infty\}$ is an example of what is called a tail event and its probability has to be 0 or 1.

Comment: I didn't think about that, yes I heard about the 0-1 law, thank you.